# How to sort Access data based on UTF-8 locale (Khmer)?

Tags: sorting, ms-access, utf-8, locale, ms-access-2013

Is there anyway to sort data in Access 2013 based on a UTF-8 Locale? Specifically, I want to sort data in the Khmer language.
Excel and Word automatically detect Khmer and sort it correctly, but I can't figure out how to get Access to sort Khmer correctly.

There was a page on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx) that gave the LCID Hex for Khmer as 0453 and the LCID Dec as 1107 but I don't understand how or if that can be used to sort Khmer correctly in Access.

Here's the sorting order for Khmer:

```
ក
ខ
គ
ឃ
ង
ច
ឆ
ជ
ឈ
ញ
ដ
ឋ
ឌ
ឍ
ណ
ត
ថ
ទ
ធ
ន
ប
ផ
ព
ភ
ម
យ
រ
ឫ
ឬ
ល
ឭ
ឮ
វ
ស
ហ
ឡ
អ
ឥ
ឦ
ឧ
ឩ
ឪ
ឯ
ឰ
ឱ
ឳ
ា
ិ
ី
ឹ
ឺ
ុ
ូ
ួ
ើ
ឿ
ៀ
េ
េះ
ែ
ៃ
ោ
ោះ
ៅ
ុំ
ំ
ាំ
ះ
័
៉
៏
៌
់
```

EDIT: I also tried to create a custom sort order as directed on [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/sort-records-in-custom-order-HA010062658.aspx), but was unable to get it to work with Khmer (it didn't follow the sort order I gave it, even with just using individual letters, let alone words).

Comment: I found a YouTube video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvHheXf5LLY) that might be of interest. If you end up using that approach please consider writing an answer to this question (in English) with a brief description of the technique you used.

Comment: Thanks Gord, hah! I guess I was searching too wide on Google! Thanks! It definitely is a hack (converting the Khmer Unicode into numbers based on the Unicode character number), but it looks like it works.

Answer (score 0):

Nathan this piqued my interest and I tried to use my computer to quickly have a go at looking into this for you. I've got some access databases that flick between Russian and English and on my Windows 8.1 computer I have keyboard support for russian cyrillics and the roman alphabet.

I find Windows 8.1 very good for language support generally and you can install differing keyboard support and Khmer is listed as a potential option. I didn't get it working but only spent 5 minutes and didn't want to install the Khmer language support on my work 8.1 computer as I never come in contact with it. But the codes that you have listed can be used to change the keyboard mapping on individual cells within MS Access. It might be that if you have the keyboard support installed access will support proper sorting. Note I have found that fields sometimes go a bit screwy if you use more unusual font types. Some fonts don't support Cyrillic for example.

I understand that Microsoft did in the past have a Cambodia Office so you might want to try and get in contact with them. I think they would know how to solve this.

Code on how to use those codes you've listed with VBA and MS Access can be found here and hopefully would work with Access 2013 and Khmer on a Windows 8.1 machine provided Khmer keyboard installation.

[VBA Function to allow alteration of Key Mapping for Multi-lingual Support in MS ACCESS](http://rounduptheusualsuspects.org/?p=39)